# iPod Charge - How to find out without disconnecting it from Computer

Tags: ipod, battery-life

How do I find out how much my iPod has charged without disconnecting it from my PC (Safely Remove Hardware and all). I connect my iPod to the USB port of my PC and it instantaneously fires up iTunes. I disconnect it, as I no longer iTunes, however my iPod is still connected to the system. 
How will I know how much it has charged, like, you know in a laptop, you move your mouse over the power symbol and it tells you how much it has charged our of 100%.

Comment: You do not mention which model of iPod you are talking out.  This is very significant.

Comment: Isn't the battery shown in the wait screen enough? The percentage you see in iTunes is an estimate, it's not a foolproof number that shows you the exact charge.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a battery idicator either on the lock screen when it's being charged or in the top right corner of the screen if it's not. But if you want to know the "exact" percentage you'll need one of the battery apps

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on "show battery percentage" in the options, it should show you.

Comment: Sorry mate, can you be more specific. Where and How can I turn on the "show battery percentage"

Comment: @thistime - I guess you are talking about an iPhone feature. My requirement is for an iPod

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.